# React Router Link not loading the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-link

I'm trying to redirect to page onclick of a button from my main page App.js, But my redirected page /SelectAirport does not seem to load.
I think there might be something with the link path but I can't figure out how to fix it.

*TLDR: The link changes but the content does not load.*

App.js

```
function App() {

    return(
        
        <div>
            <Button>
                <Link to="./SelectAirport">Select Airport</Link>
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

Full Code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-chihiro-zckfr5?file=/App.js:152-355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Routes and Route , inside of Route define your component and path for example `path='/airports'`

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import SelectAirport from "./SelectAirport";
import {
    Routes,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Button>
                <NavLink to="/airports">Select Airport</NavLink>
            </Button>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/airports' element={<SelectAirport/>}  />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

Sandbox example [Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-drake-41hwlz?file=/App.js)

Comment: Is there a way to remove the button after the airport page has loaded?

Comment: Are you want something like this ? [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-drake-41hwlz?file=/App.js) @LuisMaximus

Comment: Hi, Sorry but im facing another problem. If we use toggle that would mean that the button would not load when we press the back button how to fix?

Comment: Will it be solution for you ? [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-drake-41hwlz?file=/components/Tabs.js)

Answer (score 2):

Where is your route? You have to first create a route for `select-airport` or something like that. Currently, you are just trying to load a component directly.

The route might look like this:

```
 import SelectAirport from "./SelectAirport";
 <Route path="select-airport" element={<SelectAirport />} />
```

After this, Link will start to work, and for your case this link should be something like:

```
<Link to="/select-airport">Select Airport</Link>
```

So, whenever, it hit `select-airport`, it will try to find the matching component via `route` and load that componet.

basic example can be found here. https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/basic (v5)

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview (v6)

v6 code sample: https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/basic?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Thank you that works too, This is my first time using routers so I didn't know.